# Cannot connect to TFS althought able to access Web Acess

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-web-access

We have to expose our Team Foundation Server to the customers over the internet. One customer is able to log on using the WebAcecss (http://MyDomain:8080/tfs) but when he fires up TeamFoundationServer 2010 to connect to server from there, it simply doesn't work and he got the message: 'The underlying connection was closed:  The connection was closed unexpectedly'.
Do you know the answer to this issue?

Comment: Have you checked your firewall and made sure nothing is being blocked?  Can your client ping the TFS server and get a response?

Comment: Thanks, well. I kinda find a workaround to the problem myself a few minutes ago. I was trying to used Fiddler to view the traffic and suddenly it works, with fiddler turned on. So my guess is there's some firewall problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an firewall issue. It works when the traffic is routed through Fiddler. (I accidentally discover it when using Fiddler to find out what's going on).
These are 2 interesting articles for troubleshooting this kind of issues that I came across:

https://serverfault.com/questions/397999/team-foundation-server-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote

http://computech.in/2011/02/the-underlying-connection-was-closed-the-connection-was-closed-unexpectedly-team-foundation-server-does-not-exist-or-is-not-accessible-bypass-proxy-for-team-foundation-server/